# Fixed background images will not resize to fit mobile viewport

Tags: html, css, web, responsive-design, media-queries

The background image for the homepage will not scale down into the second homepage background image I have prepared for a mobile view-port.

On Google / Firefox dev the website renders fine on a mobile view-port but when I view the website on an actual mobile phone the homepage background image appears very zoomed in and wont display the alternative image.

I have tried to tweak my CSS and re-adjust my HTML but to no avail, the problem persists.

I will leave snippets of the HTML and CSS a link to the website for advice.

```css
#section-section1 {
  background-image: url("../images/section-1-background.png");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center right;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#section-section1 {
  background-image: url("../images/section-1-background-mobile2.png");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center right;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
    <section data-role="section" id="section-section1">
      <div class="section-1-text">
        <h1>
          <span style="font-weight: 400;">STYLE 101:</span><br />A HISTORY<br />OF
          TARTAN FASHION
        </h1>
        <button id="slide" type="button">
          <a href="#section-section2"><p>START</p></a>
        </button>
        <p class="section-1-p">Scroll down or drag sideways</p>
      </div>
    </section>
```

Link to website: http://www.07715414453.uk/

Comment: Before digging into the CSS, have you tried adding `maximum-scale` to your viewport metadata in the `<head>` of your html? `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">`

Comment: Yes its on there. Problem still persists unfortunately.

Comment: Mmm, having looked at both images, I think you might just have to tweak the mobile image: http://www.07715414453.uk/images/section-1-background-mobile2.png (It loads as expected on my Pixel.)

Comment: Glad to hear that. but on all the iphones I have tried it doesn't. I presume this must be an ios issue.. so I suppose I'll redirect the question to why it won't work on iPhones...

Answer (score 1):

When I remove the following CSS rule from all background images:

"background-attachment: fixed;"

The images then scale down when viewed on iPhone.

Comment: Hell yeah! You saved me from a headache...I was deploying like 20 times just for this bug as well, trying to tweak every possible scenario without actually seeing the result...It's working with your solution. I left the fixed on desktop view, but when it's under 450px of width, I changed the background-attachment to scroll. Works like a dream. Thank you @nedy